# Why does polygon smoothing produce a broken line?

Tags: opengl, polygon, smoothing

When using polygon smoothing in OpenGL, I get some broken lines inside my polygons as can be seen in the images:

[image]
[image]

My code looks like this:

```
glEnable(GL_POLYGON_SMOOTH)
glHint(GL_POLYGON_SMOOTH_HINT, GL_NICEST)

glPolygonMode(GL_FRONT, GL_FILL)
glPolygonMode(GL_BACK, GL_LINE)
glLineWidth(5)
glBegin(GL_QUADS)
glVertex3f(0.1, 0.1, 0)
glVertex3f(0.2, 0.1, 0)
glVertex3f(0.2, 0.2, 0)
glVertex3f(0.1, 0.2, 0)

glEnd()
glDisable(GL_POLYGON_SMOOTH)
```

Why does this happen and how can I solve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Drawing quads or polygons is usually emulated on modern hardware by drawing several triangles. When smoothing borders of these triangles, the diagonal which splits the quad into the two triangles will get smoothed too, producing this artifacts.

The OpenGL API you are using (fixed function pipeline) is deprecated for a decade now and should not be used anymore. Especially "special features" like polygon smoothing or drawing polygons might behave very differently on different hardware.

Modern OpenGL (3.3+ Core Profile) works completely different and comes with a set of better methods to deal with antialiasing like [MSAA](https://www.khronos.org/opengl/wiki/Multisampling) or post processing ([FXAA](https://blog.codinghorror.com/fast-approximate-anti-aliasing-fxaa/), ...)

Comment: I try to draw two triangles, but I get the same result

Comment: Yes, because that is exactly what the graphiccard already did. As I said: polygon smoothing works on each triangle separately. It does not take adjacent ones into account. Don't use it, use modern OpenGL and MSAA.

Comment: Thanks, I find the way to use MSAA in pyqt and pyopengl. Just add the code `fmt = QSurfaceFormat()
    fmt.setSamples(15)
    QSurfaceFormat.setDefaultFormat(fmt)` when creating a window.

Answer (score 1):

I think your blend mode is the problem. For polygon smoothing, there is the special source blend mode GL_SRC_ALPHA_SATURATE

so do try `glBlendFunc(GL_SRC_ALPHA_SATURATE, GL_ONE)`